# DataTables Fixed column search issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables and all things were working properly but when i fixed my left 3 columns the individual search part on those fixed cells are not working and also the tabs are not working.

[image]

And here is my code:

```js
var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "scrollY": 400,
    "scrollX": true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    fixedColumns:   {
        leftColumns: 3
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you add some more code?

Comment: code snippet is not working. Can you please rebuild this ?